# Renaming/Recoding variables efficiently

Tags: r, recode

I'm using R and have a dataset with ~3000 psychological test data. Most of the data is stored as string variables:

```
> table(rona_full$FQ169_6)

             At no time        Some of the time Less than half the time More than half the time 
                    418                      73                      48                      36 
       Most of the time         All of the time 
                     20                       9
```

I want to recode the string data into variables as such:

```
> table(rona_full$FQ169_6)

  0   1   2   3   4   5 
443  63  39  30  21   9
```

Currently, this is my approach:

```
rona_full$FQ169_6 <-ifelse(rona_full$MQ169_6 == "At no time", 0, #this recodes MDI from string
                    ifelse(rona_full$MQ169_6 == "Some of the time", 1,
                    ifelse(rona_full$MQ169_6 == "Less than half the time", 2,
                    ifelse(rona_full$MQ169_6 == "More than half the time", 3,
                    ifelse(rona_full$MQ169_6 == "Most of the time", 4, 5)))))
```

I imagine there is a more efficient way to perform this exact same recoding on 25+ columns rather than doing each one this way.

Comment: Best to provide reproducible example. We don't know if you have a factor variables (then what are the levels) or if it is a straight character? In the latter case your solution is not too bad.

Answer (score 1):

{data.table} is really efficient. You can use a custom function to be passed to a desired number of columns. For me this method is flexible and scalable.

```
install.packages("data.table")
library(data.table)

# dummy data
d <- data.table(id = 1:11, x = LETTERS[1:10], y = LETTERS[5:15])

# make a function suited to your needs
f <- function(x){
      as.numeric(
          fcase(
           x == "A", "1",
           x == "B", "2",
           x == "E", "5",
           x == "F", "6"
           ))}


# list of columns to where the function will be called
l_cols <- c("x", "y")

# test what you want creating new modified columns
#d[, c(paste0("new_",l_cols)) := lapply(.SD, f), .SDcols = l_cols]

# to change by reference your variables: no turning back this time
d[, c(l_cols) := lapply(.SD, f), .SDcols = l_cols]
```

EDIT: Maybe it would be more clear what´s going on if I use your data:

```
install.packages("data.table")
library(data.table)

# transform your data.frame to a data.table
d <- data.table::as.data.table(rona_full)

# make a function suited to your needs
f <- function(x){
      as.numeric(
          data.table::fcase(
           x == "At no time", "0",
           x == "Some of the time", "1",
           x == "Less than half the time", "2",
           x == "More than half the time", "3",
           x == "Most of the time", "4"
           ))}

# list of columns to where the function will be called (assuming MQ169_7)
l_cols <- c("MQ169_6", "MQ169_7")
   
# to change by reference your variables
d[, c(l_cols) := lapply(.SD, f), .SDcols = l_cols]

# confirm if it did work
head(d$MQ169_6)
```

Comment: Ok, so as evidenced by my provided code--I'm not much of a coder but I'm trying. When I try to replicate this (exactly as you've provided) I get the error: 

Error in fcase(x == "A", "1", x == "B", "2", x == "E", "5", x == "F",  : 
  could not find function "fcase"

I'm sure this is an easy fix but I'm missing it.

Comment: `fcase()` is a function of *{data.table}*, make sure you have the package installed and loaded. Other option, if you are sure that {data.table} is indeed installed, is to load just the function, using double "::", like so: `data.table::fcase(...)`. 
To be quite open with you, the *tidyverse* options given by Marcelo could be more intuitive for a begginer (or anyone else). 
Good luck!

Comment: Got it! Updated my version of R/Studio and {data.table} package fixed that issue.

Answer (score 1):

[Arthur's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66454729/8237186) is a very good solution using the `{data.table}` package. In case you are more familiar to the `{tidyverse}` way-of-life, here is another option.

### reprex first

First lets create a random data that looks like a bit like yours. I assume by
looking at your current table output that your data is read as factor. You can check
with `is.factor()`.

```
categs <- c("At no time",
            "Some of the time",
            "Less than half the time",
            "More than half the time",
            "Most of the time", 
            "All of the time")

n <- 10
df <- data.frame(
  y   = rnorm(n),
  mq_1 = sample(categs, size = n, replace = T), 
  mq_2 = sample(categs, size = n, replace = T),
  mq_3 = sample(categs, size = n, replace = T)
) %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("mq"), factor))
```

### Solution

If the naming of your variable follows a certain logic, you can use
`starts_with()` to select the variables to transform, otherwise, create a vector with
the variable names.

```
vars_to_transf <- c("mq_1", "mq_2", "mq_3")

df_transf <- df %>% mutate(
  across(starts_with("mq_"), .fns = as.numeric) #note: function without parenthesis
)
head(df_transf)
```

```
table(df_transf$mq_1)
```

### More generic option

you can also pass a custom function to the `mutate(across(.).)` functions:

```
f_trans_factor <- function(x) {
  dplyr::case_when(
    x == "At no time"               ~ 0,
    x == "Some of the time"         ~ 1,
    x == "Less than half the time"  ~ 2,
    x == "More than half the time"  ~ 3,
    x == "Most of the time"         ~ 4,
    x == "All of the time"          ~ 5,
    TRUE                            ~ NA_real_
  )
}
```

```
df %>% 
  mutate(
    across(vars_to_transf, .fns = f_trans_factor) #note: function without parenthesis
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I take it that you want to transform your dataset to factors, and you use the hand-made approach :D

You can get the factor levels by assessing the @.Data slot of a factor variable.

```
c("Foo", "Foo", "Bar") -> strings
as.factor(strings) -> factors
factors@.Data
```

Comment: This is much easier than my hand-made approach (and I got it to work, which means it's not difficult); however as far as I can tell I would still need to apply this to each column rather than scaling up to hundreds?

Answer (score 0):

This code will take unique values in a column and assign them a unique number serially:

```
rona_full$FQ169_6 = as.character(as.integer(factor(rona_full$FQ169_6, levels = unique(rona_full$FQ169_6))))
```

Comment: Useful but still requires me to apply to each column as far as I can see in my practice.